# How relevant should a tag be to add it to the question?

Tags: support, tags

I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328992/how-do-i-bind-uniform-locations-in-glsl), and got a comment that I didn't really expect:

[image: Comment on my question]

My question is: How much related to the question should a tag be before I use it? Knowledge of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) would not help in any way to answer the question, and anybody who knows Java but not GLSL/LWJGL would be completely clueless. However the code I provided is in Java.

I have always viewed tags as "I want experts in xxxx tag". Is this not the case, and should I just add all tags that relate to the question, even if people who look for those tags will be clueless about the actual question?

Should I have added the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag in this scenario?

Comment: If the question contains code in language X, add that X tag.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Adding the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag is good in this case because:

- Your post will *attract* more Java users that might know the solution for your problem
- The problem could have been in the Java code *itself*
- As mentioned in the comments by the user who suggested the Java tag, LWJGL is a Java library. If the solution suggests something that works in C but not in Java, it won't be really helping you

Comment: There's a 4th reason to add a language tag: you get syntax highlighting for that language applied by default for all the code posted (in the question *and* the answers).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Didn't think about that, it's actually very important reason :)

Comment: Expanding on your third point, a language tag like [tag:java] immediately shares with the readers a huge cargo of constraints, expectations, standard idioms, and other requirements --- more than you're likely to specify in the question itself.  It's frustrating to waste time on an otherwise-correct solution (hinging on, say, "use an _unsigned_ `int`" or "inherit from _both_") that won't work due to a constraint that wasn't stated in the question.

Comment: For langages, I agree. For servers such as data stores I would say only if directly relevant. For example if you are posting code which has no interaction with the DB, don't tag it with the DB just because the DB is somewhere in your stack.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't have seen the lwjgl tag. I *would* have seen the Java tag. I know about lwjgl; you would have missed out on my potential experience.

Answer (score 18):

The flaw with your reasoning is that people don't necessarily follow every tag/topic they are skilled with or interested in. They're search criteria - no more, no less.

So I - like I presume many others - look at questions in my primary area of interest (my language of choice). And see other tags as a way to better filter the questions.

So if you have just tagged something with a library, I wouldn't have seen it.  Even if it's a library that I've worked with routinely, and I have 'tagged' - because I'm reading the newest/active questions on my preferred language.

So in that sense - yes, I think you should have included `java` because then:

- more people will see it (and it's valid, because it's `java` you posted)
- those that have no ability to answer with your library can easily skip it.
- People with a passing familiarity or deep interest - who *may* have it tagged, might not be routinely searching on that tag anyway.
- people with a passing interest might find it useful to know which language the supplied code is written in.

I would go as far as saying that almost every question on Stack Overflow *should* include at least one "language" tag, simply because of the nature of what is "on topic". If it's not specific to one (or maybe a couple of related) language, then it's often *too broad*.

Comment: The exception to the language-tag rule is algorithm questions.  Or you could count algorithm pseudo-code as a language, or as meaning "any language which can be ported to other similar languages".

Comment: There is also the [tag:language-agnostic] tag.

Answer (score 6):

I don't always read every question in the tags I follow.  Questions with multiple tags that I like are more likely to get my attention.  If someone knows GLSL but not the java bindings for it, they're a *lot* less likely to be able to *quickly* figure out what the problem is.

I was writing this when Sobrique's answer was posted, so I'll stop here.  This should maybe just be a comment.  I hope this is meta enough for you.